# How to generate class files manually in Eclipse plugin development?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I want to generate class files to some place(not the output folder in the build path) manually ,i found some classes like JavaBuilder,Compiler,IncrementalProjectBuilder,etc,but i still dont know how to use these classes to compile class files to a specified location.How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate a little what is it you need/want to do?

Comment: The question is unclear - you want to programatically generate the class files or you want build Eclipse plug-ins?

Comment: For Eclipse plug-ins you can either use PDE build outside of Eclipse or use Eclipe to generate your plug-in feature or product.

Answer (score 0):

You can let Eclipse generate the class files in the bin directory and use Ant to copy the class files to whichever directory (WEB-INF?) you wish.